# Unable to mount data partition in android edify updater script

Tags: android, android-firmware, edify

I am newbie here with edify updater scripting

I am able to mount system partition using following statement:

```
mount("ext4", "EMMC", "/dev/block/system", "/system");
```

but not able to mount data partition.
I tried following statements to mount data partition without success:

```
mount("ext4", "EMMC", "/dev/block/data", "/data");

mount("ext4", "MTD", "/dev/block/data", "/data");

mount("ext4", "EMMC", "/dev/block/mtdblock8", "/data");
```

Output of "blkid" shows 3 partitions:

```
/dev/block/system
/dev/block/cache
/dev/block/data
```

Output of "cat /proc/mtd" shows "data" is linked with "mtd8".

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

For partition-type "EMMC", you correctly provide the block device as the 3rd parameter. For "MTD", you need the mtd partition name, which in your case propbably is "data" or "userdata" - see /proc/mtd.